# Callback after successful login to social media application

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, instagram-api

I have an application which needs to let users to login via social networks: Facebook, Twitter, Instagram.
I was wondering if there is a way to configure the provider (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram) with a callback url to our backend server when a user has successfully logged in.
I know I can let the mobile app send it to me but I was looking for some generic and more robust solution.

P.S: I have tried the Facebook Login product with Valid OAuth redirect URIs but I didn't receive anything when a user logs in.

Comment: _“I have tried the Facebook Login product with Valid OAuth redirect URIs but I didn't receive anything when a user logs in”_ – that’s because that field has nothing to do with that; it is used in the login flow for web apps. // For Facebook I can tell you for sure that such a thing does not exists, and my guess would be that it is the same with the other networks. This is just not a common use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for webhooks?

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks
- https://dev.twitter.com/webhooks